# jQuery code won't work on IE8, but does on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Have have made some jQuery that makes my navigation dropdown, show and hide on hover. 
For some weird reason it doesn't work on IE8 and IE7.

When testing with a `Console.log()` It executes correctly on hover on, but not the `$('div', this).show();` part...

My jQuery version is: v1.9.1

My code

```
$("nav ul li").hover(
  function () {
    $('div', this).show();
  },
  function () {
     $('div', this).hide();
  }
);
```

Comment: Use the developer tools to see if there are any errors being thrown in IE7 and 8.

Comment: There is no errors thrown.

Comment: I always wrap `this` in `$(this)` when i get the children of this object. Try it like this `$('div', $(this)).hide();`

Comment: `<nav>` is an HTML 5 tag. Does IE8 support it?

Comment: I found the solution... I should next check my IE.css file for some old forgotten `overflow: hidden` on my nav wrapper.. Sorry folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
  $(".class").on('mouseenter', your_function);
```

Comment: Not working, can't even make it say anything in the console.

Answer (score -1):

Use old jQuery version for proper support in ie6+

Check it here.

http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: IE9 is supported in 1.9.1